# While Reading CSV, last column is coming as Null in Spark, Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

When I am trying to read a pipe separated file using Spark and scala like below:

```
1|Consumer Goods|101|
2|Marketing|102|
```

I am using the command:

```scala
val part = spark.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("delimiter","|")
    .load("file_name")
```

I am getting result as:

```
+---+--------------+---+----+
|_c0|           _c1|_c2| _c3|
+---+--------------+---+----+
|  1|Consumer Goods|101|null|
|  2|     Marketing|102|null|
+---+--------------+---+----+
```

Spark is reading last column which is not present in source file because of delimiter mentioned as pipe.
Is there any alternative to this where I can get result as:

```
+---+--------------+---+
|_c0|           _c1|_c2|
+---+--------------+---+
|  1|Consumer Goods|101|
|  2|     Marketing|102|
+---+--------------+---+
```

Comment: >>Spark is reading last column which is not present in source file .... because you have "|" in end of the line for every column. read it as textFile and split data by pipe and and spill out tuple data excluding last index value in split

Comment: drop the last column after you create the dataframe.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to simply drop the last column like this:

```scala
part
  .select(part.columns.dropRight(1).map(col) : _*)
  .show(false)
+---+--------------+---+
|_c0|_c1           |_c2|
+---+--------------+---+
|1  |Consumer Goods|101|
|2  |Marketing     |102|
+---+--------------+---+
```

Another solution would be to read the file as a text file and split it yourself like this:

```scala
val text = spark.read.text("file_name")
// Note that the split functions in java/scala/spark ignores a separator that ends
// a string, but that one that starts one
val size = text.head.getAs[String]("value").split("\\|").size

text
  .withColumn("value", split('value, "\\|"))
  .select((0 until size).map(i => 'value getItem i as s"_c$i") : _*)
  .show(false)
+---+--------------+---+
|_c0|_c1           |_c2|
+---+--------------+---+
|1  |Consumer Goods|101|
|2  |Marketing     |102|
+---+--------------+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below options

```
df.drop(df.columns(0)) -- for dropping last column in scala

df.drop(df.columns[-1]) -- for dropping last column in pyspark
```